# Getting CacheException when querying in ignite

Tags: caching, ignite

I am new to Ignite and actually using spring boot application to interact with ignite. I have ingested cache into ignite and fetched cache from ignite through keys. But if i try to fetch cache through query API i am getting the following exception.

```
[16:56:55,225][SEVERE][http-nio-8080-exec-2][[dispatcherServlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.cache.CacheException: Indexing is disabled for cache: testCache. Use setIndexedTypes or setTypeMetadata methods on CacheConfiguration to enable.] with root cause javax.cache.CacheException: Indexing is disabled for cache: testCache. Use setIndexedTypes or setTypeMetadata methods on CacheConfiguration to enable.
```

Following is the code for my implementation:

When i invoke this method i am getting the above exception

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/query/cache", produces = "text/html")
private String queryCache(Model model) {
    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) {
        // Load cache with data from the database.
        CacheConfiguration<Long, IgnitePerson> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("testCache");
        IgniteCache<Long, IgnitePerson> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);
        SqlQuery<Long, IgnitePerson> query = new SqlQuery<>(IgnitePerson.class, "select * from IgnitePerson");
        List<Entry<Long, IgnitePerson>> list = cache.query(query).getAll();
        personsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Entry<Long, IgnitePerson> entry : list) {
            personsList.add(entry.getValue());
        }
        model.addAttribute("persons", personsList);
    }
    return "cacheresults";
}
```

This works fine and i am getting cache from ignite

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/read/cache", produces = "text/html")
private String readCache(Model model) {
    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) {
        // Load cache with data from the database.
        CacheConfiguration<Long, IgnitePerson> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("testCache");
        IgniteCache<Long, IgnitePerson> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);
        Set<Long> keys = new TreeSet<>();
        keys.add((long) 1);
        keys.add((long) 2);
        Map<Long, IgnitePerson> map = cache.getAll(keys);
        personsList = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        model.addAttribute("persons", personsList);
    }
    return "cacheresults";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not configure SQL schema and indexing - this is required if you want to run queries. Refer to this page for details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have added `cfg.setIndexedTypes( Long.class, IgnitePerson.class);` to the cache configuration befor injesting data inside cache. And my IgnitePerson class variables are annotated with @QuerySqlField, i have added ignite-indexing module inside libs. I have started only one ignite node using  _"ignite.bat /examples/config/example-ignite.xml"_. But still i am getting this following exception. 'javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to execute query. Add module 'ignite-indexing' to the classpath of all Ignite nodes'

Comment: Where do you get it? On server or on client? Note that you need the indexing module available everywhere.

Comment: Actually i am getting that on client if i am not wrong. I am using spring boot application and through api trying to query. How can we add that module to client through api. Let me understand this when we are doing any operations on ignite cluster, java api creates a client ignite server on the fly and ingest/query the data over the cluster. Is that correct.? Please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: On client you should add ignite-indexing.jar and its dependencies. You can do this via Maven or other dependency manager.