# Does Apache ignite allows query on partition key of Cassandra table without considering cluster key?

Tags: cassandra, ignite

my table structure ;

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.person (
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    age int,
    birthdate timestamp,
    married boolean,
    phone text,
    PRIMARY KEY (firstname, lastname)
);
```

and i wanna get all person details have firstname 'abc'.
as i'm providing only partition key ,not cluster key.

getting result from cache only when specify both partition and cluster key.

tried sql query also but gives error table not found.

[error pic][1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFem2.png

cache config is as below:

```
<!-- Persistence settings for 'cache1' -->
<bean id="cache1_persistence_settings" class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.persistence.KeyValuePersistenceSettings">
    <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource" value="classpath:persistence/primitive/persistence-settings-1.xml" />
</bean>

<!-- Ignite configuration -->
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <!-- Configuring persistence for "cache1" cache -->       
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="cache1"/>
                <property name="readThrough" value="false"/>
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="writeBehindFlushSize" value="2"/>
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.CassandraCacheStoreFactory">
                        <property name="dataSourceBean" value="cassandraAdminDataSource" />
                        <property name="persistenceSettingsBean" value="cache1_persistence_settings"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="clientMode" value="false"/>
    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <!--
                    Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                    instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                    to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                -->
                <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>192.168.0.3:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
```

and have used pojo strategy for key and value.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite allows to search in cache by any fields (not mandatory partition and cluster keys). How properly configure SQL in Apache Ignite read there:https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs#queryentity-based-configuration

Comment: i tried that my cache name is cache1 and table is person, have tried but it unble to find that ,even used AffinityKeyMapped & QuerySqlField too.

Comment: Could you share your configuration file?

Comment: You don't configure Ignite Indexing. You need configure them via annotations or 
QueryEntity. Read this page https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/indexes

Comment: sorry for late reply ,but i found that and configured too even in config file now sql and scan query too working fine and thanks for ur help @nikolay

Comment: i have one more issue read-though not woking properly. please see [Read-through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540606/how-read-through-work-in-ignite)

Answer (score 0):

i found that is because of index config in cache config file 
refer this link [config index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875317/getting-cacheexception-when-querying-in-ignite) and [Failed to execute SQL](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Failed-to-execute-SQL-from-ODBC-Indexing-is-disabled-for-cache-td8924.html) . its woking just by adding below lines

```
 <property name="queryEntities">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                            <property name="keyType" value="com.manish.igniteexample.PersonKey"/>
                            <property name="valueType" value="com.manish.igniteexample.Person"/>

                            <property name="fields">
                                <map>
                                    <entry key="firstname" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                    <entry key="lastname" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                    <entry key="age" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
                                    <entry key="married" value="java.lang.Boolean"/>
                                    <entry key="birthDate" value="java.util.Date"/>
                                    <entry key="phone" value="java.lang.Integer"/>
                                </map>
                            </property>

                            <property name="indexes">
                                <list>
                                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                        <constructor-arg value="firstname"/>
                                    </bean>
                                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                        <constructor-arg value="lastname"/>
                                    </bean>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
```