# how read-through work in ignite

Tags: persistence, ignite

my cache is empty so sql queries return null.
The read-through means that if the cache is missed, then Ignite will automatically get down to the underlying db(or persistent store) to load the corresponding data.

If there are new data inserted into the underlying db table ,i have to down cache server to load the newly inserted data from the db table automatically or it will sync automatically ?

Is work same as Spring's @Cacheable or work differently.
It looks to me that the answer is no. Cache SQL query don't work as no data in cache but when i tried cache.get in i got following results  :

case 1:

```
 System.out.println("data == " + cache.get(new PersonKey("Manish", "Singh")).getPhones());
```

result ==> data == 1235

case 2 :

```
PersonKey per = new PersonKey();
per.setFirstname("Manish");
System.out.println("data == " + cache.get(per).getPhones());
```

throws error:- as following 
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy6hO.png), [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfwrZ.png)

Comment: read-through is true in my config file

Answer (score 5):

Read-through semantics can be applied when there is a known set of keys to read. This is not the case with SQL, so in case your data is in an arbitrary 3rd party store (RDBMS, Cassandra, HBase, ...), you have to preload the data into memory prior to running queries.

However, Ignite provides native persistence storage [1] which eliminates this limitation. It allows to use any Ignite APIs without having anything in memory, and this includes SQL queries as well. Data will be fetched into memory on demand while you're using it.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store

Answer (score 4):

When you insert something into the database and it is not in the cache yet, then *get* operations will retrieve missing values from DB if *readThrough* is enabled and *CacheStore* is configured.

But currently it doesn't work this way for SQL queries executed on cache. You should call [loadCache](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#loadCache(org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteBiPredicate,%20java.lang.Object...)) first, then values will appear in the cache and will be available for SQL.

When you perform your second *get*, the exact combination of `name` and `lastname` is sought in DB. It is converted into a CQL query containing `lastname=null` condition, and it fails, because `lastname` cannot be `null`.

**UPD:**

To get all records that have `firstname` column equal to 'Manish' you can first do `loadCache` with an appropriate predicate and then run an SQL query on cache.

```java
cache.loadCache((k, v) -> v.lastname.equals("Manish"));

SqlFieldsQuery qry = new SqlFieldsQuery("select firstname, lastname from Person where firstname='Manish'");

try (FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(qry)) {
    for (List<?> row : cursor)
        System.out.println("firstname:" + row.get(0) + ", lastname:" + row.get(1));
}
```

Note that `loadCache` is a complex operation and requires to run over all records in the DB, so it shouldn't be called too often. You can provide null as a predicate, then all records will be loaded from the database.

Also to make SQL run fast on cache, you should mark `firstname` field as indexed in `QueryEntity` configuration.

Comment: to call loadCache i have to provide keys, and without that i cant load new value. as in my scenario i have only firstname value not lastname , as cassandra raw queries allows to query on one of that only.

Comment: @ManishJaiswal don't have to provide keys to perform loadCache. loadCache takes an optional predicate. I updated the answer and added more details about it.

Comment: thanks a lot , that query worked but only for first time after remote server start. when executed program for second time sql or text cache query not working until i restart my ignite remote server.

Comment: @Denis, could you say, how Ignite gets to know if SQL table was modified and one need to update Ignite cache?

Comment: @IldarZaripov Ignite doesn't know that automatically. That's why it's recommended to avoid updates to the DB itself. You can either configure [write-through](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/persistence/external-storage#read-through-and-write-through) and do the updates through Ignite or set up an [expiry policy](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/configuring-caches/expiry-policies), so that stale entries are removed from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

In your case 2, have you tried specifying `lastname` as well? By your stack trace it's evident that Cassandra expects it to be not null.

Comment: no as i haven't specified lastname is taken null value .

Comment: @ManishJaiswal please try specifying it.

Comment: @ManishJaiswal that's strange, can you share error screenshot?

Comment: @ManishJaiswal And can you please update the code snippet? If you indeed specified both firstname and lastname there, maybe somewhere else in your code (in POJO for example) you have two fields annotated `firstname` and none annotated `lastname`?